# clouldformation with boto is not listing resources for stack

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

```
cf_connection = boto.cloudformation.connect_to_region('us-east-1', aws_access_key_id='mykey',
                                                      aws_secret_access_key='mysecret')

resource = cf_connection.list_stack_resources(stack_id)
print resource
```

This list does not contains Physical ID, rather it is giving me the Logical ID and Type
Also how can I filter this list

everything is available in CLI

```
        "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:myid", 
        "ResourceStatus": "CREATE_COMPLETE", 
        "ResourceType": "AWS::EC2::XYZ", 
        "Timestamp": "time", 
        "StackName": "mystack", 
        "PhysicalResourceId": "myphysical", 
        "LogicalResourceId": "myLogicalName"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `list_stack_resources` method returns a list of `StackResourceSummary` objects.  Each object has the following attributes:

- last_updated_time
- logical_resource_id
- physical_resource_id
- resource_status
- resource_status_reason
- resource_type

You can use these attributes on each object in the list to get the detailed information you are looking for.

Try this code:

```
import boto.cloudformation
conn = boto.cloudformation.connect_to_region('us-east-1', ...)

resources = conn.list_stack_resources(stack_id)
for resource in resources:
    print(resource.last_updated_time)
    print(resource.logical_resource_id)
    print(resource.physical_resource_id)
    print(resource.status)
    print(resource.resource_type)
```

And tell me what you see.

Comment: yes its returning StackResource: but I only get two objects logicalId and Type.

Comment: Sound Like it is a bug.